# Default in grey and selected item in green

Tags: html, css

I have a select menu.

```css
    select.empty {
        color: grey;
    }
    select.option{
        color:green;
    }
```

```html
    <select class="empty">
        <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
        <option value="1">Item 1</option>
        <option value="2">Item 2</option>
        <option value="3">Item 3</option>
    </select>
```

I want to have the first option in `grey`. So that it's similar to a placeholder. Now when the user selects an option how can I make the text green? At the moment it's `grey`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use like  this tested in chrome also working fine

```
select option[disabled=""] {
  color:grey;
}
select option{
  color:green;
}
```

thanks hope this helps

**Snippet**

```css
select option[disabled=""] {
  color:grey;
}
select option{
  color:green;
}
```

```html
<select class="empty">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
  <option value="1">Item 1</option>
  <option value="2">Item 2</option>
  <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `:checked` pseudoclass for the green color of the selected option. This is an example code that should work

```css
.empty option, .empty option:disabled:checked {
    color: grey;
}
.empty option:checked{
    color:green;
}
```

```html
<select class="empty">
   <option value="" selected disabled>Please select</option>
   <option value="1">Item 1</option>
   <option value="2">Item 2</option>
   <option value="3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. Somehow it does not recognize the class on the option. It works when using selector `option:checked`, but that's not what Becky was after.

Comment: @arnoudhgz I now edited the answer with a working code (will not work for IE 7 and below).